# Adding an item to a drop down list for data validation when the initial list is a named range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that contains the list of values that I want to use in my named range - A, B, and C.

Fairly simple to have them be the named range - `=Indirect("Table1[Column1]")`

However, I would like "All" to be an option for this particular drop down table.

My initial attempt was to use `=Indirect("Table1[Column1]"), All`, but that didn't work at all.

It would be trivial to add "All" to the table in question, but I'd like to avoid that option if possible.

How can I get "All" added to my drop down list without manipulating the source table directly? I'm willing to use named ranges, but I can't figure out how to add to an array. I imagine if there was something like =Array(Range1, Range2) I could get it to work.

I can get this to work using VBA to make a UDF, but I'm trying to find a non-VBA solution.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998771/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-non-contiguous-values-from-a-row-in-excel-ignoring-blank) to generate a contiguous list from non contiguous ranges aand see if it get you  on the right track.

Comment: I've used that particular formula a few times - the issue is, it relies a bit too much on column/index numbers. To put it another way, it's no different from having "All" in a cell, then having the rest of the table in an array under it, then creating a new named range refering to it. It is a valid solution - I'm hoping to see if I can accomplish the same thing without creating a new table

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

**How it works:**

- Name to multiple columns using OFFSET formula can help to create DROP DOWN lisr for DATA VALIDATION.

  `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$T$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$T:$T),2)`
- Where, `COUNTA($T:$T)` is being used to determine how many rows to expand down and `2` is the number of columns to include.
- `Sheet1!$T$2` skips the Column Header from Drop Down list.

**Note:**

- *Table Columns can be used as other Columns (without Table Reference).*
- *Adjust Sheet Name & Column reference as needed.*

Comment: This is very cool to make a NxM matrix into a 1xN*M matric, and get all the results! I can't quite see how to apply it to just add a single item to a matrix though - doing it with this method seems like it would create a large amount of whitespace

Comment: @Selkie, if you have blank Cells the it will or any list to Drop Down will create lots of White Spaces !!